# do elementary matrices for sums of rows need to have ones on the diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have always thought that any addition of two rows of a matrix could be described by an elementary matrix, such as for example: 
$\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ puts the sum of twice the frst row and the second row into the first row.

A colleague of mine says instead that row addition must be expressed always with a one on the diagonal. So, the above example should be represented by first performing the operation
$\begin{bmatrix}1&0.5\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and then $\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

I looked up a few textbooks and, while none states that this must be true, they seem to use this convention.

Can anybody suggest why my colleague could be right?

Comment: Having numbers other than $1$ on the diagonal changes the determinant, but that's pretty much the only distinction.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. Maybe my colleague's suggestion is better for teaching purposes. Thanks.